# Criação de Grafo em forma de Dicionário retornando inteiros

Tags: python, dicionário

Estou implementando um código em Python para criação de Grafo

```
with open (filename, "r") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split()
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = [value]
        else:
            d[key].append(value)
```

Porem meu Algorítimo está retornando  o dicionario em string e não inteiro, olhem minha saída:

```
{'1': ['2', '4', '5'], '0': ['1'], '3': ['2', '7'], '2': ['3 ',' 6 '],' 5 ': [' 6 '],' 4 ': [' 5 ',' 0 '],' 7 ': []' 6 ': [' 5 ',' 7 ']}
```

como faço para converter para inteiro o key e o value ou obter tudo como inteiro?

Comment: Aí tem algum erro ou apenas a saída não está como esperado?

Comment: somente a saída deveria gerar um Grafo com inteiros e não string.

Comment: Você quer tanto a chave quanto o valor como inteiros? Ou basta os valores? (se quiser a chave também, use `int` também em `key`, só tome cuidado pra fazer isso antes de testar sua presença no `dict`, não depois)

Answer (score 3):

Você está lendo um arquivo. Natural que sejam *strings*.

Para tipar para inteiro, modifique seu código para o seguinte:

```
with open (filename, "r") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split()
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = [int(value)]
        else:
            d[key].append(int(value))
```